# Using relative paths for assets for heroku deployment

Tags: assets, config

I cant quite wrap my head around the way the way the heroku file system works, so I'd like to use relative paths for my asset File System Paths. Is that even possible?

I've tried to use `CRAFT_BASE_PATH` in the general settings file to define an environmental variable, but no real luck getting my assets folders to be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Multi-Environment Configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) and specifically [environmentVariables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables). Then you can [add your variables to the settings](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#setting-support) in the Craft CP.

Note: you'll have to figure out Heroku's paths by trial and error or ask their support staff for help.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of — I dont have any issue with the Multi-Environement configs, its more trying to avoid having to plumb the depths of the heroku file system.